# How to create scenario in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter tool for load testing. I want to create scenario in JMeter for Load testing of my web application. I want to know the process of creating scenario in JMeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the different steps :-

1. 1.Go to JMETER_HOME/bin and start JMeter with jmeterw.cmd on Windows and jmeter on Linux/Unix

   1. Select “Test Plan” on the tree
   2. Right click on the “Test Plan” and add a new thread group: Add > Threads (Users) > Thread Group
   3. Select the Thread Group
   4. Right click “Add -> Config Element -> Http Request Defaults”
      6.6. In new HTTP Request Defaults element: Server name – enter “jakarta.apache.org”
   5. Path – leave blank Right click on the “Thread Group” and add a recording controller: Add > Logic Controller > Recording Controller
   6. Next, select WorkBench
      10.Right click on WorkBench and add the Http proxy: Add -> Non-test elements -> Http Proxy Server
      11.Right click on “HTTP Proxy Server” and add a listener: Add -> Listener -> View Results Tree
      12.Return to HTTP Proxy Server, and click the “Start” button at the bottom

you can also follow this links::
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf